# Is there any function transformation calculator?

Tags: functions, transformation

I'm searching for a tool which allows me to enter two functions and that returns if they are a transformation of each other and how this transformation looks like. Does it exist?

My example from down below:

Is $ u_1(x) = (\frac{1}{\gamma})x^\gamma$ a transformation of $u_2(x) = \frac{x^\gamma -1}{\gamma}$ ?

And in this case, I know the answer is yes there is a positive linear transformation because $$T(u_1(x)) = u_1(x)-\frac{1}{\gamma} = u_2(x).$$ So the question would be, if there is a tool that gives me this kind of answer.

Comment: I do not know such a tool, and I can barely imagine that there is a tool that can handle arbitary complicated expressions. I guess someone wrote a program that can handle relatively easy cases, maybe someone on this site can help.

Comment: If this is related to linear algebra (according to tags), what vector space are you working with? Are these functions you speak of elements of a vector space, or are they something else? What is meant by these functions being transformations of each other? If you edit your question to include this context, someone might be able to narrow down what you’re looking for.

Comment: I think, linear algebra was wrongly chosen.

Comment: Still, if you add an example of what you mean, then maybe some kind user will be able to edit the tags appropriately. I suspect that this question might actually be about function composition somehow? Are you looking for something that, given functions $f$ and $g$, will find a function $h$ such that $f = g \circ h$?

Comment: Is $ u_1(x) = (\frac{1}{\gamma})x^\gamma$ a transformation of $u_2(x) = \frac{x^\gamma -1)}{\gamma}$ ? And in this case, I know the answer is yes, because $T(u_1(x)) = u_1(x)-\frac{1}{\gamma} = u_2(x)$. So the question would be, if there is a tool that gives me this kind of answer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by transformation', but as a way to check various cases I would use Wolfram Mathematica

Comment: If you had a general formula for transformation (like $g(x) = a \cdot f(bx+c) + d$) you could try solving for values of the variables that make this equation work for all $x$. Depending on what computer algebra system you're using, it may make it easier to plug in several specific values of $x$ to get a series of equations in just $a,b,c,d$ to solve. ($g(0) = a f(0b+c)+d$, $g(1) = a f(1b+c)+d$, etc.)